# Is there a way to repeat a variable in an echo without having to type it multiple times?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to shorten the echo?
I need the variable to be in a single line and repeats itself.

```
@echo off
set a=asdfghjk
echo %a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%%a%
pause>nul
```

I am a beginner, and that is the only way I tried it.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Use a `for` loop, and instead of using `echo` use `set` with it's `/p` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set example=123
:loop
echo|set /p="%example%"
goto loop
```

You can also do it through **[for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)**

Comment: So - where's the `for` ?